# Redefining "cited on" string (and others) in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, languages, naming

I'm trying to modify the strings `biblatex` uses to set the "cited on" string used in the bibliography to identify the pages where a given references has been cited.

What I gather from the `biblatex` documentation (e.g., § 4.9.2.16) is that something like

```
\renewbibmacro{backrefpage}{<newtext>}
\renewbibmacro{backrefpages}{<newtext>}
```

ought to work, but they have no effect for me (I'd also like to get this working for the "visited on" string, `urlseen`).

My MWE is unchanged from [How do I turn titles into hyperlinks in verbose mode using BibLaTeX and hyperref?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49564/how-do-i-turn-titles-into-hyperlinks-in-verbose-mode-using-biblatex-and-hyperref), with the addition of these (and related lines) just about anywhere.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The original definitions (full and abbreviated version) can be found in the language-specific `.lbx` files. Here's the relevant code snippet from `english.lbx`:

```
  backrefpage      = {{cited on page}{cit\adddotspace on p\adddot}},
  backrefpages     = {{cited on pages}{cit\adddotspace on pp\adddot}},
```

These strings are declared using the `\DeclareBibliographyStrings` command which is only available in `.lbx` files. Outside these files, you have to use `\DefineBibliographyStrings` which *"overrides both the full and the abbreviated version of the string"* (`biblatex` manual, section 3.8).

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  backrefpage = {<newtext>},
  backrefpages= {<newtext>},
}
```

Comment: @domwass I could feel someone else was typing. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick! Incidentally (dumb question, perhaps) why does something like `\renewbibmacro*{in:}{<newtext>}` work.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Because this bibmacro uses the bibstring "in" internally.