# "in" untranslated for French incollection and article bibliography entries

Tags: biblatex, babel, french

Instead of showing the French word `dans`, BibLaTeX is putting `in` to introduce booktitles and journals. For example

```
@incollection{rodgers99,
    Address = {London},
    Author = {Roders, C.},
    Booktitle = {Modern France: Society in transition},
    Date-Added = {2013-03-30 21:06:06 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2013-03-30 23:09:27 +0000},
    Editor = {Cook, M. and Davie, G.},
    Pages = {53-72},
    Publisher = {Routledge},
    Title = {Gender},
    Year = {1999}}
```

comes out as

> Sellier, G. (2002). « Construction des identités de sexe dans les séries policières françaises. » In : Les séries policières. Sous la dir. de G. Sellier et P. Beylot. Paris : L’Harmattan, p. 259–271.

as opposed to

> Sellier, G. (2002). « Construction des identités de sexe dans les séries policières françaises. » Dans : Les séries policières. Sous la dir. de G. Sellier et P. Beylot. Paris : L’Harmattan, p. 259–271.

Obviously, I've included `babel` and everything (hence most of it is translated), so I can only assume this is a bug?

I've only just started using LaTeX, can I just edit the `french.lbx` file in the `biblatex` package or is that a bad idea?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's always a bad idea to edit package files in the installation path. If you want to provide your own package file you should do this in your local texmf tree or in your working directory.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that if this hasn't been fixed by the time I come to hand this in.  Thanks very much.

Comment: You can also do some changes in your tex file. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50102/redefining-cited-on-string-and-others-in-biblatex/50104#50104

Comment: But “in” is commonly employed, particularly in the Humanities: it's the Latin word, not an anglicism. Undoubtedly this is why it hasn't been “translated”: there's no need. Much more debatable, in my opinion, are the colon that follows “in” and the period that separates from what precedes it, whereas, traditionally, a comma is used.

Comment: Just tell me what it should ideally be and I'll correct it in biblatex for the next release. There are all sorts of missing translation parts - if you can contribute changes to french.lbx, I'd be glad.

Comment: Just to answer the last bit of the question: You should not edit the `french.lbx` from the `biblatex` installation of your TeX system. If you manually change a file installed by your system these changes can be overwritten by updates or re-installs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently there is not comment agreement on whether such strings should be latin or french, see for example the discussion on the `biblatex` github https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/1022 (thanks to Moewe for pointing this out).

Should you wish to override the current default latin with a french equivalent you can do that in your document using `\DefineBibliographyStrings`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[french]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{in={dans},inseries={dans}}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{test}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

where `ref.bib` contains

```
@Article{test,
  author =   {Author, A. N.},
  title =    {Title},
  journal =  {Jour.},
  year =     2011
}
```

Comment: If translations are incorrect, that should be reported at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues. In this case the situation doesn't seem to be as clear cut as it appears to be at first, see for example the discussion in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/1022.

Comment: @moewe Many thanks for this. I have rephrased the beginning of the answer.