# Biblatex : replace "In" by another entry in APA style

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, strings, french

I would like to put the strings like "In" in french (so "Dans") in a APA bibliography with biblatex.
I tried to use the answer of this post, it works until I put the biblatex style in apa : [Replace "in" in specific entries biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469154/replace-in-in-specific-entries-biblatex) .
I also tried to with this answer but the problem is the same : [Biblatex: add "submitted to" or "to appear in" for some publications](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408024/biblatex-add-submitted-to-or-to-appear-in-for-some-publications) .

Has somebody a solution to this problem, please ?

The main file :

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
%\DeclareLanguageMapping{french}{french-apa}
\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily} % remove smallcaps
\addbibresource{sample.bib} 
\input{string.tex}

\begin{document}
\cite{lopez2016-1}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The string file (I can more or less understand what is wrote but I can't write that) :

```
\NewBibliographyString{toappearin}
\NewBibliographyString{submittedto}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  toappearin  = {to appear in},
  submittedto = {submitted to},
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
  toappearin  = {Dans},
}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \ifboolexpr{not test {\iffieldundef{pubstate}}
              and (test {\iffieldequalstr{pubstate}{toappearin}}
                   or test{\iffieldequalstr{pubstate}{submittedto}})}
    {\printtext{%
       \printfield{pubstate}\intitlepunct}%
     \clearfield{pubstate}}
    {\printtext{%
       \bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
```

The sample file :

```
@incollection{lopez2016-1,
    author = {Lopez, G{\'e}rard and Bouasker, Anissa},
    title = {Le psychotraumatisme},
    pages = {4 - 28},
    editor={Lopez, G{\'e}rard and Sabouraud-S{\'e}guin, Aurore},
    series = {Les ateliers du praticien},
    publisher = {Dunod},
    isbn = {978-2-10-074590-6},
    year = {2016},
    booktitle = {Traiter les psychotraumatismes},
    language = {fre},
    address = {Paris},
    keywords = {Traumatisme psychique -- Thérapeutique},
    lccn = {978-2-10-074590-6},
    pubstate = {toappearin},
}
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106180/35864 help?

Comment: Wow, much more easy. I haven't found this post. It's works, thanks a lot !