# biblatex (authoryear-ibid): all names last-first & name separator

Tags: biblatex

So I have some rough fulfillment of a thesis' formal requirements already. The status quo is attached in full in the MWE. It essentially consists of tidbits I asked for on this very site.

Some source-unrelated things that need fixing:

- the comma behind the author in the references should be omitted.
- the order of the names should be last-first for all names, but it does not work in the references and in the bibliography, the order only works for the first name.
- the names in the references are not separated by `/` (it's currently `and`).

Since I got the `last visit` bit for the `urlseen`-key to work myself (which is huge in relation to my knowledge of biblatex), I think only source-related left is some stuff for *InCollection* / *InProceedings* sources (these publications should all be formatted according to this one style definition).

The order of the following elements should be (elements not mentioned should stay as they currently are):

1. article title
2. "in:"
3. name(s) of editor (editors), by the scheme last-first with the first name(s) in initials
4. "(editor)" or "(editors)"
5. proceedingstitle/collectiontitle/maintitle
6. no. of proceedingstitle, if there is any
7. edition of proceedingstitle, if higher than 1
8. location of publisher
9. pages

This is the status quo:

> **Brandt, A. von/E. Hoffmann (1987):**
>   Die nordischen Länder von der Mitte des 11. Jahrhunderts bis 1448, in: Europa im Hoch und
>   Spätmittelalter, Seibt, F./Smith, J. (editors), 4th ed., Handbuch der europäischen
>   Geschichte, no. 2, Klett-Cotta, Stuttgart, pp. 884–917.

An example of what it should be like:

> **Brandt, A. von/Hoffmann, E. (1987):**
>   Die nordischen Länder von der Mitte des 11. Jahrhunderts bis 1448, in: Europa im Hoch und
>   Spätmittelalter, in: Seibt, F./Smith, J. (editors): Handbuch der europäischen
>   Geschichte, no. 2, 4th ed., Klett-Cotta, Stuttgart, pp. 884–917.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper
]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}


\usepackage[
language=auto,
style=authoryear-ibid,
backend=bibtex,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
citereset=chapter,
maxcitenames=3,
dashed=false,
sorting=nyt,
firstinits=true,
ibidtracker=true,
maxbibnames=99
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}

%% comma after every item for bibiliography entries
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

%%  parentheses around year in references
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
\iffieldundef{labelyear}
{}
{%
\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
\printtext[parens]{%
\printfield{labelyear}%
\printfield{extrayear}}}}}

%% correct order of publisher and location
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
\newunit
\printlist{publisher}%
\newunit
\printlist{location}%
\newunit}

%%  right order of words 'volume' und 'issue' with comma in front
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}% THIS LINE CHANGED to add comma
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

%taken from standard.bbx
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printtext{%   REMOVED parenthesis here
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \usebibmacro{date}}}%
  \newunit}

%% bold bibliography "label" followed by colon and linebreak
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\mkbibbold\bgroup}
\xapptobibmacro{date+extrayear}{\addcolon\egroup}{}{}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\par\nobreak}

%% linebreak before URLs and colon before date of last visit
\xpretobibmacro{url+urldate}{\setunit{\newunitpunct\par\nobreak}}{}{}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
urlseen = {last visit\addcolon}
}

%% colon before date of last visit
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\addcolon\space#1}}

%% no indent
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt} 

%% one empty line between to bib-entries
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip} %% \baselineskip gibt hier an, dass Zeilenabstand unterhalb des Absatzes der dokumentweite Abstand ist

%% ``(editor)'' or ``(editors)''

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}
\xpatchbibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}{\printtext}{\printtext[parens]}{}{}

%%  ``(editor)'' or ``(editors)'' instead of ``(ed. by)''
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
byeditor = {editor},%
byeditor = {editors},%
issue  = {\lowercase{i}ss\adddot},%
}

%% all titles in references in normal formatting
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1\isdot} 

%% annul format of any title whatsoever in bibliography and add comma+space
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1\addcomma\addspace} 

%% Format von Titeln als ganz normal!
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1\addcomma\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1\addcomma\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{issuetitle}{#1\addcomma\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{maintitle}{#1\addcomma\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{proceedingstitle}{#1\addcomma\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{collectiontitle}{#1\addcomma\addspace}
%new
\DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{\bibstring{volume}~#1\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{issue}{\bibstring{issue}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1} %comment to leave number as before
\DeclareFieldFormat*{series}{{#1}\addcomma\space} %comment to leave number as before

%% Names: Lastname, Firstname
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
    %% only slash signs between authors
    \renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addslash}
    \renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addslash}
    %% only slash signs between multiple locations
    \renewcommand{\multilistdelim}{\addslash}
    \renewcommand{\finallistdelim}{\addslash}
}

\begin{filecontents*}{lit.bib}
@InCollection{brandt,
  options     = {useprefix=false},
  hyphenation     = {german},
  author      = {von Brandt, Ahasver and Hoffmann, Erich},
  editor      = {Seibt, Ferdinand and Smith, John},
  title       = {Die nordischen L{\"a}nder von der Mitte des 11.~Jahrhunderts bis 1448},
  booktitle   = {Europa im Hoch- und Sp{\"a}tmittelalter},
  series      = {Handbuch der europ{\"a}ischen Geschichte},
  number      = {2},
    edition = {4},
  publisher   = {Klett-Cotta},
  location    = {Stuttgart},
  date        = {1987},
  pages       = {884--917}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{lit.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{References}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Something for the one \verb+InCollection+.\footcite[See][p. 5--11]{brandt}
    %\item For the \verb+book+-type.\footcite[See][p. 2]{cicero}
    %\item For the source type \verb+online+.\footcite[See][]{itzhaki}
    %\item For the \verb+article+: Some word.\footcite[See][p. 70]{gillies}
\end{itemize}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can suppress fields in the bibliography with `\clearfield` and friends. This has already been covered in various places, including [lockstep's guide](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13076). For the remaining problems, consider editing this post. A question posed in terms of "before" and "after" images is neither clear to potential answerers nor useful to anyone looking for similar help.

Comment: Well I was sure the question was posed based upon the "minimal" working example I provided, the images are clearly serving as a display. :/ But I'll go fishing for little bugs some more before I return, I see it is just a big mess.

Comment: By "editing" I meant spelling out exactly what you want. The `byeditor` string in paretheses? You've already [asked about that](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113570/4483), so just include Marco's code here. The colon after `urlseen`? Use `\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\addcolon\space#1}}`. I am pretty sure this will help, but I have no idea whether or not I have entirely answered the question.

Comment: It did. Alright, a big edit is incoming to pinpoint the changes.

Comment: Edit finished. :)

Comment: OK, I gave an answer. Next go-round make your question more clear and confined. Any users also wanting to print `edition` with `number` are unlikely to come across your question in a search, which really defeats the purpose of this Q&A format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the name list format add to your preamble:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
```

The bibliography drivers issue `\printfield{edition}` directly. An easy way to defer printing until after the series/number fields is to clear `edition` and restore it later. The following code demonstrates this approach. It can also be added to your preamble.

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \iffieldequalstr{edition}{1}
    {\clearfield{edition}}
    {\savefield*{edition}{\savededition}%
     \clearfield{edition}}}

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \restorefield{edition}{\savededition}
  \printfield{series}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit}
```

If you only want to defer printing for `@incollection` and `@inproceedings` entry types use this hook instead:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \iffieldequalstr{edition}{1}
    {\clearfield{edition}}
    {\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifentrytype{proceedings}} or test {\ifentrytype{incollection}} }
       {\savefield*{edition}{\savededition}%
        \clearfield{edition}}
       {}}}
```