# Citing two authors gets displayed incorrectly

Tags: biblatex, author-number

I have a problem with my citations, I want to cite an article with two authors, A Surname and B Lastname. I write it as following in my .bib file:

```
@article{crillersen,
Author = {Surname, A and Lastname, B},
Title = {Random title},
Year = {2006},
Pages = {1,9 and 14},
Journal ={some journal},
url={http://www.someurl.com/},
}
```

I get the result:

> Surname, A and B Lastname (2006). "Random title". I:some journal, 1, 9 and 14. url:http://www.someurl.com/.

The setup I am using is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel} 
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Why do I get the surname first on the first person and the first name first on the second person? I have tried to look though previously asked questions but found nothing about this.

How can I print this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A similar problem seems to be mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121217/biblatex-authoryear-ibid-all-names-last-first-name-separator).

Add the following to the preamble:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
```

Previously, I suggested to use `last-first` instead of `family-given`, which is equivalent but now deprecated as pointed out below in the comments.

Comment: Note that starting with version 3.3 you should use `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}` instead. `last-first` is only supported as legacy alias and should produce a warning.