# Selectively citing full month name with biblatex-ieee?

Tags: biblatex, datetime, ieee-style

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  bibencoding=utf8,
  backend=biber,
  natbib,
  style=ieee, % this abbreviates month always!
  dateabbrev=true, % but this (alone) seems to have no effect on month abbreviation?
  isbn=true,
  url=true,
  defernumbers=true,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article {jo-audm08,
  author = {Some Author},
  title = {{Testing the title of a paper}},
  url = {http://example.com/paper.pdf},
  journal={Proceedings of Some Conference},
  pages={123--127},
  publisher = {example.com},
  year={2008},
  month={jun},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citemonth}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {%
    \let\oldabx@bibmonth\abx@bibmonth%
    %\let\abx@bibmonth\blx@imc@biblstring\typeout{CHG: abx@bibmonth \meaning\abx@bibmonth}% false: not abbreviated; but nowork
    \setkeys{blx@opt@pre}{dateabbrev=false}% nowork
    \mkbibmonth{\thefield{month}}%
    \let\abx@bibmonth\oldabx@bibmonth% restore
  }
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Testing month: \citemonth{jo-audm08};

% \printbibliography[sorting=none]

\end{document}
```

I compile with `pdflatex test.tex && biber test && pdflatex test.tex && pdflatex test.tex`. No matter what I do, the output is "`Testing month: Jun.;`"; I'd like to get "`Testing month: June;`".

My attempt in the MWE above is based on the assumption that the abbreviation is due to the `biblatex` option `dateabbrev=false`; but then I looked into `texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-ieee/ieee.bbx`, and what do I see:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{  
  june      = Jun\adddot ,
  july      = Jul\adddot ,
  september = Sep\adddot ,
}
```

So, apparently this is why June is abbreviated - but *why* are *only* these three months abbreviated??!

So in principle I could override the `\DefineBibliographyStrings` in the preamble, which will have global effect - but let's say I want to keep this default behavior (these three months abbreviated), and have the full month names output only when I use `\citemonth`; is that possible, and if so, how to do it?

---

EDIT: Uh, this is gonna be complicated: [Redefining "cited on" string (and others) in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50102/redefining-cited-on-string-and-others-in-biblatex)

> The original definitions (full and abbreviated version) can be found in the language-specific .lbx files. ... These strings are declared using the `\DeclareBibliographyStrings` command which is only available in .lbx files. Outside these files, you have to use `\DefineBibliographyStrings` which "overrides both the full and the abbreviated version of the string" (biblatex manual, section 3.8).

If I could use `\DeclareBibliographyStrings` in preamble, I could just write `june = {{June}{Jun\adddot}},` as per `english.lbx` -- but I can't use it there, and I don't want to hack `english.lbx`; and so otherwise I'd have to use `\DefineBibliographyStrings` which overwrites both forms. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it; first, why are only those three months redeclared? If you look at `english.lbx` in the `\DeclareBibliographyStrings` - all abbreviated months are abbreviated to first three letters + dot, except for these three; and the IEEE style apparently requires abbreviation at three characters.

In terms of the fix: basically, I make a "shallow" copy of `\DeclareBibliographyStrings` skipping any checks called `\ReDeclareBibliographyStringsEnglish`; the trick here is that if `\ReDeclareBibliographyStringsEnglish` is ran in preamble, it will be overwritten by defferred `biblatex` setups - so any setup using `\ReDeclareBibliographyStringsEnglish` must run after begin document. Otherwise, locally changing `dateabbrev` works fine: for instance, the fixed MWE below now outputs:

> Testing month: June;
>   Testing date: Jun. 2008;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  bibencoding=utf8,
  backend=biber,
  natbib,
  style=ieee, % this abbreviates month always!
  dateabbrev=true, % but this (alone) seems to have no effect on month abbreviation?
  isbn=true,
  url=true,
  defernumbers=true,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article {jo-audm08,
  author = {Some Author},
  title = {{Testing the title of a paper}},
  url = {http://example.com/paper.pdf},
  journal={Proceedings of Some Conference},
  pages={123--127},
  publisher = {example.com},
  year={2008},
  month={jun},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\def\ReDeclareBibliographyStringsEnglish#1{% from \DeclareBibliographyStrings in \blx@lbxinput@ii, biblatex2.sty; skipping any checks
 %\begingroup % works if not wrapped in begin/end group!
 \let\blx@defstring\blx@lbx@defstring
 \blx@defbibstrings{english}{#1}%
 %\endgroup%
}%
\def\RunReDeclare{%
  \ReDeclareBibliographyStringsEnglish{% only in preamble!
    june             = {{June}{Jun\adddot}},
    july             = {{July}{Jul\adddot}},
    september        = {{September}{Sep\adddot}}, % orig english.lbx has Sept\adddot; IEEE is Sep\adddot
  }%
}%
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citemonth}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {%
    \let\oldabx@bibmonth\abx@bibmonth%
    %\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{% only in preamble!
    %  june      = June,%
    %  july      = July,%
    %  september = September,%
    %}%
    %\let\abx@bibmonth\blx@imc@biblstring\typeout{CHG: abx@bibmonth \meaning\abx@bibmonth}% false: not abbreviated; but nowork
    \setkeys{blx@opt@pre}{dateabbrev=false}% nowork; actually, work for true!
    \mkbibmonth{\thefield{month}}%
    \let\abx@bibmonth\oldabx@bibmonth% restore
  }
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

% NOTE: the \def of \ReDeclareBibliographyStringsEnglish can
% NOT sit in preamble; apparently its effect will be overridden
% by deferred setups of biblatex running at \begin{document}
% so must execute this after the \begin{document}!
\RunReDeclare

Testing month: \citemonth{jo-audm08};

Testing date: \citedate{jo-audm08};


% \printbibliography[sorting=none]

\end{document}
```