Hyperlink for in-text cite that redirects you directly to doi or arxiv website
I usually put in text citations on my beamer based talks, but since I do not put a references slide the hyperlink is of no use. I would like to have in-text citations redirect directly to either the doi website or the arxiv website. Any ideas?

Pretty easy with biblatex: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/384638/35864 (shown there only for the DOI, but arXiv links could be added as well as shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226075/35864). With BibTeX or manual thebibliography it would be trickier because you'd need a way to extract the bib data, which is generally not available in citations.
